# How to change the color of icon in Tabbar? (react-native-navigation)

Tags: ios, react-native, navigation, react-native-navigation

I want to just show pure icon image in TabBar
but in iOS, it's displayed like this.

[image]

but original images are below.

[image]

I think it is basic in IOS. I want to remove the color or to set be transparent.
Is it possible?

I tried to change tabsStyle for some test below.

```
tabsStyle: {
    tabBarBackgroundColor: '#000',
    tabBarButtonColor: '#fff',
    tabBarSelectedButtonColor: '#fff',
  }
```

[image]

Left image is work but Right image is strange.

## Environment

React Native: "0.55.2"

react-native-navigation: "^1.1.438"

Platform: iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's solved.

I'm using react-native-navigation "v2" now.

This is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tabStyle` . For e.g

```
tabsStyle: {
    tabBarBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    tabBarButtonColor: '#fff',
    tabBarSelectedButtonColor: '#fff',
  }
```

Comment: I tried this but it's not display anything because all of things become white.

Comment: Please post your tabsStyle.

Comment: tabsStyle: {
    tabBarBackgroundColor: '#000',
    tabBarButtonColor: '#fff',
    tabBarSelectedButtonColor: '#fff',
  }